# Self bias FET circuit

Tags: circuits

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am trying to follow the book’s steps, but I cannot get the same quadratic they did to solve for Vgs. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Show us your work. How can we spot your mistake if you don't share your work?

Comment: If I read it correctly your first handwritten line doesn't match units, neither left to right side, nor inside the right side of the equation. If so, it's no surprise the rest will fail.